# Android self-publishing - potential issues

Tags: android

After some thought I'm leaning towards self-publishing my Android App. I already read this:
[Advantages of publishing an app in Android Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648332/advantages-with-publishing-app-in-android-market)

Why:
Because Google doesn't give me straight answer and I don't wan't any legal issues. My app is FREE on market but I will charge monthly subscription price for it. Neither I want to pay Google 30% (app is just a client to web-service which I host) nor they allow me to do monthly subscription.

So.. What kind of issues I expect when self-hosting? I have full control over host, I can do pretty much anything. I know users need to allow non-Market apps. I can incorporate self-update mechanism into my app(downloading new version on background and then just asking user to install)

What phone companies in US do not block non-Market apps? Is there other stuff I need to watch for?
I will miss error-reporting feature that Market provides. Can I implement it into my app somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What phone companies in US do not block non-Market apps?

Most AT&T phones do not support non-Market apps, but they have reversed their policy recently. I am not aware of any other carriers with issues here, though you could check the instructions from the Amazon Appstore for installing apps, as you'll have the same distribution issues they do (just smaller).

> Is there other stuff I need to watch for?

I hope you have a marketing plan, but that's beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

> I will miss error-reporting feature that Market provides. Can I implement it into my app somehow?

Try [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) or any of the other third-party frameworks for this.

Comment: Thank you! I have my own logging and error sending code so ACRA will be too much but I think I will implement just what they do. I need to create my own service and watch for exceptions in separate thread. As far as marketing - no problem. Issue with Market outweights it's marketing value :)